# Javascript/jQuery: Get specific elements from form

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have an extense form with around 25 inputs (text, radio and checkboxes). I want that when I click the button that opens the jQuery dialog, loads the form and set all fields except 5 of them disabled. Seems so easy, but I want that into a "generic" function. I mean, that I have this method:

```
function disableInputs(jQueryElement, exceptions, booleanClean) {
    //Some stuff
}
```

I want to get all the inputs from the `jQueryElement`, but ignoring all the elements with the ids that have `exceptions`. `Exceptions` is an Object like this one:

```
var exceptions = {
    0: 'clientId',
    1: 'clientName',
    2: 'clientFirstSurname',
    3: 'clientSecondSurname',
    4: 'clientAlias'
}
```

This is my full code and what I've tested, but this is the only way to make it work and, if I have recieved the third parameter (`booleanClean`), It will set `value=''` to all `inputs`, instead to the elements that weren't excluded from being disabled. That boolean works to check if you want to clean inputs when this function is called:

```
function disableInputs(jQueryElement, exceptions, booleanClean) {
    var inputs = jQueryElement.find('input');
    for (var i = 0; i < inputs.length; i++) {
        inputs[i].setAttribute('disabled', true);
        for (var attr in exceptions) {
            if (inputs[i].getAttribute('id') === exceptions[attr]) {
                inputs[i].removeAttribute('disabled');
            } else {
                if (booleanClean === true) {
                    inputs[i].value = null;
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

I know why is not working the clean "option". What I want is where I have to put that to do it properly or if I can set a condition when I get the inputs to get only the inputs that are not excluded (preferible second option for optimization and not set an attribute to each input and remove them if are excluded. Seems much easier to work).

Comment: Why is `exceptions` not an array: `['clientId','clientName','clientFirstSurname',...]`

Comment: @nnnnnn Well, It's the same using an `array` or an `object` here. It will work anyway. This will not solve my problem, but thanks anyway.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try

```
function disableInputs(jQueryElement, exceptions, booleanClean) {
    var not = jQuery.map(exceptions, function(item, index){
        return '#' + item;
    }).join(',')
    var inputs = jQueryElement.find(':input').not(not).prop('disabled', true);
    if(booleanClean){
        inputs.val('')
    }
}
```

Comment: Thank you so much! this worked perfectly. If I understood what it does, it returns the names from the object `exceptions` with an '#' before the name, and when it finds the `inputs`, ignores the inputs that have that `ids` and adds the property disabled to the rest of elements, right?

Answer (score 2):

I'd suggest changing the `exceptions` object to be a conventional array:

```
var exceptions = ['clientId',
                  'clientName',
                  'clientFirstSurname',
                  'clientSecondSurname',
                  'clientAlias'];
```

...because then you can simplify your function a *lot:*

```
function disableInputs(jQueryElement, exceptions, booleanClean) {
    var inputs = jQueryElement.find('input');
    if (exceptions.length > 0) {
        exceptions = "#" + exceptions.join(",#");
        inputs = inputs.not(exceptions);
    }
    inputs.prop("disabled",true);
    if (booleanClean)
        inputs.val("");
}
```

I'm a bit confused about whether you want to clean *all* inputs or just the ones not on the exceptions list. My code above just cleans those not on the list. To clean them all move that `if(booleanClean) inputs.val("");` to before the other `if` statement.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. But I prefer @ArunPJohny answer, because I can use both, `objects` and `arrays` to define my exceptions argument. To answer you, I wanted to 'clean' the inputs that weren't at the `exceptions` list. +1

Comment: You're right, I shouldn't have implied that you can't simplify without an array: as you've said, the other answer would handler either way. Still, in a general sense an array makes more sense than an object if your object just has numeric properties like that.

Comment: Yeah, that's true, but maybe one day, in any other project may use names instead of numbers to define object properties (to understand it better or something like that). I accept your suggestion about using an array ;) also tried using an array, but I was unable to let it work anyway, I was stucked hehe

Answer (score 0):

Are you able to give a class name to the items that are exceptions? That's what I would do.

```
<input class="exception" />

$( "input:not(.exception)" ).prop("disabled", true);
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this one:

HTML

```
<form>
    <input type="text" name="input1" value="val1" />
    <input type="text" name="input2" value="val2" />
    <input type="text" name="input3" value="val3" />
</form>
```

JS

```
function disableInputs(jQueryElement, exceptions, booleanClean) {

    jQueryElement.find('input').not( exceptions.join(', ') ).each(function(){

        if( booleanClean ){
            $(this).val('');
        }

        $(this).prop('disabled', true);

    });

}


var exceptions = ['input[name=input1]', 'input[name=input3]'];

disableInputs( $('form'), exceptions, true );
```

Here is working sample: http://jsfiddle.net/4Dwwk/

Comment: Already answered and solved, but thank you anyway. It's a good reference ;)